# How can pass the model property as an argument in a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to pass model class property as an argument to the method `IsNameDuplicateAsync` and use the model class property name from the argument. I am trying to check the Product Description is already in the database. So how can I rewrite the code using the property name as from the argument

```
if (await IsNameDuplicateAsync<Product>("Description"))
 {
        var tested = "Ok";                      
 }
public async Task<bool> IsNameDuplicateAsync<TModel>(string columnName) where TModel : class
{
   return await Set<TModel>().AnyAsync(x => x.Name == "TestName");
}
```

I am trying to bring the code as given below

```
return await Set<TModel>().AnyAsync(x => x.Description== "TestName");
```

Comment: What is `Set` in this case? What is `TModel`?  It looks like you aren't using any models but trying to execute an ORM query with EF Core. The whole point of using ORMs is to give the impression of working with objects, eg `db.Customers.AnyAsync(c=>c.Name==somename)` not tables, rows, and strings.  If you *don't* want to work that way, it's a *lot* easier to either write the SQL query or use a micro-ORM like Dapper.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Newer versions make it easier to work with ad-hoc queries. LINQ-to-Entities works with *expressions*, so you may be able to pass a `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>` expression to your method, if it's simple enough. For complex expressions you may have to use LinqKit

Comment: `x => EF.Property<object>(x, columnName) == "TestName"`. See docs: [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-7.0) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-7.0) method. With it, the code turns out to be the simplest.

```
public async Task<bool> IsNameDuplicateAsync<TModel>(string columnName, object value)
    where TModel : class
{
    return await Set<TModel>().AnyAsync(x => EF.Property<object>(x, columnName) == value);
}
```

Call:

```
IsNameDuplicateAsync<Product>("Description", "TestName"))
```

There is a disadvantage here that you can make a typo in the property name, which will lead to an error at runtime.

I can suggest another option that gives a stricter typing of the code.

```
public async Task<bool> IsNameDuplicateAsync<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expr)
    where TModel : class
{
    return await Set<TModel>().AnyAsync(expr);
}
```

Call:

```
IsNameDuplicateAsync<Product>(x => x.Description == "TestName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to access the property by its name passed as an argument.
For example:

```
if (await IsPropertyDuplicateAsync<Product>("Description", "TestName"))
{
    var tested = "Ok";
}

public async Task<bool> IsPropertyDuplicateAsync<TModel>(string propertyName, string propertyValue) where TModel : class
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The property '{propertyName}' does not exist in the type '{typeof(TModel).Name}'.");
    }

    return await Set<TModel>().AnyAsync(x => (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(x) == propertyValue);
}
```

Comment: This won't translate into SQL. It's about Entity Framework.